# open iptables whithin docker-compose network and one external server

Tags: linux, iptables, docker

Im Trying to deploy a system using docker compose which contains mysql server.
The server is shared between the docker containers in the same network.

I need to access the mysql db from a specific external server in our network, so i published the mysql port (3306) within the docker compose file.

But as a security concern I wan to block any other ip who tries to access this port.

I tried many iptables rules and all of them either blocked containers within the docker-compose or allowed other servers to access the port.

p.s. I will all change the user permissions within the mysql server, but blocking the port is the first thing we want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may configure the iptables entries in the DOCKER-USER table. This is done outside of docker. E.g. if you are worried about requests on the eth0 interface to port 3306 from any network other than 10.0.0.0/24:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 ! -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp \
  -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 3306 -j DROP
```

Note that `conntrack` and the conn track original destination port are needed rather than a normal tcp port rule to handle the NAT rules and port mapping.

Comment: This rule didn't work because the rule docker adds within DOCKER *catches* packets from other servers before the suggested rule.
I am pretty sure this rule was added by docker when I set it to publish the 3306 port

Comment: I managed to solved it using the two following rules:
`iptables -I FOWARD -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP`    
`iptables -I FOWARD -i eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`    
`iptables -I FOWARD -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`    

The only problem is when I restart the docker it puts its own rules again and they are located before my rules..